# no CSS3 INTELLISENSE using WEBSTORM 2.1.2 EDITOR

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova-3

i am using WebStorm inorder to make simple html5 and css3 file.
trying to use CSS3

```
    transform: rotate(15deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(15deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
```

but my webStorm 2.1.2  is not allowing me to write CSS related to **transform** and **Overlay**  even there is no INTELLISENSE please let me know may i need to upgrade my WebStorm. While all other CSS properties are there.

Comment: Just a tip, always use the vendor prefixed versions and then put the standard as last, not the inverse.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried version 7.0.1, with the CSS examples you wanted to work, and can confirm that they **do not** work in the current version of WebStorm either. They are completely ignored even though the W3C validator accepts the non-vendor-specific `transform`.

FYI: It's called "code completion".

There's an [open issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-105) apparently. If you're interested in it getting fix, you'll need to vote on it.

Comment: I submitted a bug report -- we'll see where that goes.

Comment: You'll definitely need to upgrade to the latest version to take advantage of it assuming they fix it.

Comment: Added detail about the open issue.